# Multiple Toggle button default selected values in Angular 7

Tags: angular, toggle, default, selected

I'm looking to instantiate the default values for a mat-toggle-button-group. For some reason whenever the multiple attribute is used, the values are not set like it should.

For a single default value in a toggle-group without multiple attribute, there is no problem. And I thought it would work the same way, but apparently it doesn't. 
My code looks like this :

Main html.component where I use the form with an Input

```
    <app-customer-form [customer]="updateCustomer"></app-customer-form>
```

inside the form is a part with a toggle button for the companies that are related to the customer:

```
    <mat-button-toggle-group  #groupCompany="matButtonToggleGroup" 
             multiple="true"
             [value]="selectedCompanies"
             (change)="onValueChange(groupCompany.value)" 
             >
             <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let item of companyList" 
         [value]="item">{{item?.name}}</mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
```

in the ts file I'm retrieving the companies inside my object and storing the values inside the array/object selectedCompanies. The companyList is retrieved and works fine. I checked with the console.log and the selectedCompanies is instantiated like expected and contains the correct values. But the toggle buttons are not selected.

It is kind of hard to put the ts.file in here because it is really nested with other components. But in short it looks like this. When a row in the table component is clicked, it emits an event to the parent component with the value of the customer, and inside the object there is the property of companies. The emitted value is used to fill the form with the toggle button.

form.ts file :

```
export class FormComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
@Input() customer : ICustomer; 
companyList: ICompany[];
selectedCompanies: ICompany[];
constructor( 
    private companyService : CompanyService,
    public sharedService : SharedServices
    ) {}
ngOnInit(){
this.instantiateForm(); // retreives the values for the companyList and 
                        // other default values.
}
ngOnChanges() {
this.setSelectedCompanies();
}
setSelectedCompanies(){
this.selectedCompanies = this.customer.companies
}
```

Anyone any thoughts about this?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you add the screenshots of what is appearing currently ?

Comment: @SanyamGoel Yeah, I added it in the next comment. Tnx for your help!

Comment: Please remove the result from the answers. I am able to do this.

Now can you post the code from ts file for selectedCompanies and companylist how are they managed ?

Comment: It would be nice If you can post both your HTML and ts file or a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/). SSCEE is also a defacto for posting issues for a faster resolution on stack overflow

Comment: @SanyamGoel in my edit I tried to give you some more details about my components. I'm still new to all this but I hope this will help you understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: When I console.log the selectedCompanies, I get the expected result after the ngOnChanges. I have other toggle buttons that works fine, but they all are single selected.

Comment: Let me know the below helps to sort your problem or more specifically you will have to post something like in below to get better help. Something that can be executed and debugged that can replicate your problem

Comment: If the answer helped, you may up vote as well ;) by clicking up arrow

Comment: Well I did, but it doesn't count it yet because I'm new to this site :)

Comment: No problems at all. Just one thing since you are new to stackoverflow 
1. Always  try to create a SSCCE and post the problems, and help can be expected instantly.
2. Use tags that helps to cite the problem
3. Be descriptive both in title and body to help the reader to get better help.
4. And have a nice journey on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine. I think you are referring to two different objects having same attribute values:

see this component html code :

```
<p>
  Default appearance:
  <mat-button-toggle-group name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style">
    <mat-button-toggle value="bold">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="italic">Italic</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="underline">Underline</mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
</p>

<p>
  Legacy appearance:
  <mat-button-toggle-group appearance="legacy" name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style"   multiple="true" [value]="selectedCompanies">

    <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let company of values" 
         [value]="company">{{company?.name}}</mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
</p>
```

And typescript code for the component

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Button toggle appearance
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'button-toggle-appearance-example',
  templateUrl: 'button-toggle-appearance-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['button-toggle-appearance-example.css'],
})
export class ButtonToggleAppearanceExample {

 values:Comapny[]= [];

 selectedCompanies:Comapny[]=[];

  ngOnInit() {

this.values.push (new Comapny("First Company", "Address 1"));
this.values.push (new Comapny("Second Company", "Address 2"));
this.values.push (new Comapny("Third COmpany", "Address 3"));

this.selectedCompanies.push(this.values[0]);
this.selectedCompanies.push(this.values[1]);

  }

}


class Comapny {

constructor (name:string, address:string){
   this.name=name;
   this.address=address;
  }

  name:string;
  address:string;
}
```

try running it here by replacing [code](https://stackblitz.com/angular/nneqopqxmrv?file=app%2Fbutton-toggle-appearance-example.ts)

Here is the output with a multi-attribute and two selected buttons

[image]

**Please make sure you are referencing the same objects in both the lists**

Comment: Tnx, it helped a lot, it seems the difference was that i assigned the value of customer.companies to selectedCompanies instead of pushing it into the selectedCompanies. That makes it work :)